# Brand profit and loss

Tags: java

This code works well, but it's too long and looks too bad. I've tried to format it, but it all sets data, so I don't know how to make it better.

Here is the class:

```
private static BrandProfitAndLoss getAllRateComparisonRecords(BrandProfitAndLoss brandProfitAndLoss , BrandProfitAndLoss brandProfitAndLossComp){
    BrandProfitAndLoss result = new BrandProfitAndLoss();
    result.setDate(brandProfitAndLossComp.getDate());
    result.setOrder_item_num_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_item_num(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_item_num()));
    result.setOrder_count_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_count(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_count()));
    result.setOrder_price_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_price(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_price()));
    result.setOrder_amount_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_amount(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_amount()));
    result.setOrder_gross_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_gross(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_gross()));
    result.setOrder_wholesale_price_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getOrder_wholesale_price(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getOrder_wholesale_price()));
    result.setDelivery_count_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getDelivery_count(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getDelivery_count()));
    result.setDelivery_price_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getDelivery_price(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getDelivery_price()));
    result.setDelivery_item_num_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getDelivery_item_num(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getDelivery_item_num()));
    result.setDelivery_gross_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getDelivery_gross(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getDelivery_gross()));
    result.setDelivery_amount_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getDelivery_amount(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getDelivery_amount()));
    result.setApproval_rate_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getApproval_rate(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getApproval_rate()));
    result.setShipping_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getShipping(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getShipping()));
    result.setAll_delivery_price_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getAll_delivery_price_comp(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getAll_delivery_price_comp()));
    result.setReturn_sales_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getReturn_sales(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getReturn_sales()));
    result.setPoint_discount_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getPoint_discount(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getPoint_discount()));
    result.setPoint_allowance_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getPoint_allowance(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getPoint_allowance()));
    result.setSales_amount_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getSales_amount(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getSales_amount()));
    result.setPurchasing_cost_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getPurchasing_cost(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getPurchasing_cost()));
    result.setProfit_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getProfit(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getProfit()));
    result.setProfit_gross_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getProfit_gross(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getProfit_gross()));
    result.setYfc_cost_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getYfc_cost(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getYfc_cost()));
    result.setCommission_cost_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getCommission_cost(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getCommission_cost()));
    result.setServer_cost_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getServer_cost(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getServer_cost()));
    result.setBrand_cost_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getBrand_cost(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getBrand_cost()));
    result.setBrand_pol_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getBrand_pol(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getBrand_pol()));
    result.setCompLastYearRate_comp(compareData(brandProfitAndLoss.getCompLastYearRate(), brandProfitAndLossComp.getCompLastYearRate()));
    return result;
}
```

And here is the `compareDate` method:

```
private static float compareData(float thisYear, float lastYear) {
    float result = 0;
    if(thisYear == 0 || lastYear == 0){
        return result;
    }

    return (thisYear / lastYear) - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the `BrandProfitAndLoss` class? If so, consider something like the Builder pattern. This will have the additional benefit of likely allowing the instance you return to be immutable.

Since the scope of your `brandProfitAndLoss` and `brandProfitAndLossComp` variables is pretty small, consider a shorter variable name. It just bulks up each line, and you're unlikely to lose track of the variable since you can see its entire lifespan at one time.

Make `result` and your parameters final variables.

Make your methods more consistently named, you're using some odd combination of camelCase and underscores that is hard to read and easy to mix up. Java is most often camelCased, but adherence to any standard is better than a mishmosh.

Rename your method: it does not appear that this class "gets all rate comparison records". It seems to generate some sort of single comparison record and return it.

Rename your other method: `compareData` is undescriptive as to what the method does.

Regarding `compareData`:
There's no sense in storing a value into a variable if you're only using it once (in the case of `result`). Also, you should not be using floats to store data that refers to money, as it will NOT work the way you hope it will. There are appropriate classes in Java for handling money in predictable ways (e.g. BigDecimal), you should use those wherever possible.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to get accomplished with this method, so I can't suggest much. Is it just to show which of those numbers is greater? Can you use some kind of inline comparison in the setters above? Perhaps the classes (even, say, Float) support compareTo (from the Comparator interface), which would simplify this a lot.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 just for "shorter variable names". Using e.g. `b1` and `b2` instead of `brandProfitAndLoss` and `brandProfitAndLossComp` will make each line 36 characters shorter and much more readable.

Comment: @James McMillan thank for your help, it's very necessary for me

Comment: -1 for shorter variable names - the problem with this method is already readability, you're trying to compensate for an unclear design by taking unnecessary shortcuts.  But +1 for the comment on camelCase - it's not standard Java convention to use underscores in method names.

Comment: @Trisha Partially agreed. The names of the _method parameters_ should be kept long and descriptive, but in the method _body_, shorter names pointing to the same objects could be used.